# Magento how to place order form box and add to cart button in sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to place "order form box" with add to cart button in my right sidebar of the theme. i tried to edit layout.XML but not lucky to do that.how we can place this to sidebar in every product page. i am working on this page

---

[image: placing order form in sidebar]

hi i want place order form in right side bar

Comment: Please explain it a little more in detail. What exactly you require and if possible paste an image showing how you want it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `<form>` tag that has to wrap around the options. This form tag only exists in the `catalog/product/view.phtml` and does not include the right column.

One option would be to **fake** the box in the right column, hide the one echoed in the `view.phtml` and then set the options with javascript.

All in all it'll be quite a challenge to get this working properly (but that might just be because I'm a horrible frontender).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make this page **1-column** and put **new container** after **content** block. Then using css build your page as you like. Physically you will not have **right sidebar**, but visually you can do the same view. There is disadvantage of this approach - you need to reassign all blocks from right container to your new block.